# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int _{2n}^{3n}\frac{x+3}{x^2+1}\,dx?$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

How to evaluate
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int _{2n}^{3n}\frac{x+3}{x^2+1}\,dx?$$
The answer in the book is $\ln\frac a2$ where $a$ is a constant.

Attempt:

$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_{2n}^{3n}\:\frac{x+3}{x^2+1}dx =\lim_{n\to\infty}[\frac12\ln(x^2+1)+3\arctan x]^{3n}_{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}[\frac12\ln(9n^2+1)+3\arctan3n-\frac12\ln(4n^2+1)-3\arctan2n]=\infty
+\frac{3\pi}2-\infty-\frac{3\pi}2$

and no $\ln\frac a2$. Can someone explain to me how to evaluate this limit?

Thanks!!

Comment: Anyway, I think that $\ln (a/2)$ is a terrible answer, because $a$ may be anything ($a >0$).

Comment: Indeed, $\ln(9n^2+1)$ and $\ln(4n^2+1)$ both diverge but $\ln(9n^2+1)-\ln(4n^2+1)$ converge to a nice limit. If you can identify it, your exercise is solved...

Comment: Where does the $a$ come from? It is not present in the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Since $n \to \infty$ you can asymptotically approximate $$\frac{x+3}{x^2+1} \sim \frac{1}{x}$$
Hence the limit becomes
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{2n}^{3n} \frac{x+3}{x^2+1} \ \mathrm{d} x =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{2n}^{3n} \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{d} x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln (3n/2n) = \ln (3/2)$$

Comment: One has to be so careful to check that the conditions which ensure that the limit of the integral is indeed the limit of the equivalent, are met in the present case, that this answer is verging on being misleading.

Comment: One can show that $\frac{x+3}{x^2+1}-\frac1x=\frac{3x-1}{x(x^2+1)}$ is $O(x^{-2})$, resulting in an $O(n^{-1})$ error.

Comment: @Did If $f\sim g$ at $\infty,$ then $\int_{2n}^{3n}f \sim \int_{2n}^{3n}g$ as $n\to \infty.$ So if $\int_{2n}^{3n}f\to L,$ then $\int_{2n}^{3n}g\to L.$

Comment: @zhw. The first implication in your comment is the one which is true **and** needs justification. (Sorry but what is your point exactly?)

Comment: @Did I think we agree that asymptotic equivalence is sometimes used sloppily around these parts to claim various magical things. This seemed to me to be one of the more straightforward of the cases that arise, so I wrote that little bit. I do think a mention from Crostul on this would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the last limit expression:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac12\ln(9n^2+1)+3\arctan3n-\frac12\ln(4n^2+1)-3\arctan2n\right)$$
The arctangent terms both tend to $\frac{3\pi}2$ as you have noticed, so they cancel in the limit and can be removed:
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac12\ln(9n^2+1)-\frac12\ln(4n^2+1)\right)$$
Now combine the two logarithms into one:
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12\ln\frac{9n^2+1}{4n^2+1}$$
Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{9n^2+1}{4n^2+1}=\frac94$, we can replace it and obtain the desired form:
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12\ln\frac94$$
$$=\ln\frac32$$
Hence $a=3$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{3}{2})$

Comment: @D.Rotnemer What? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @D.Rotnemer If you choose to post cryptic comments, at least post the good one, which is: $\frac12\ln\frac94$ (and which does not apply to this answer...).

Comment: you forgot to multiply $ln(\frac{3}{2})$ by $\frac{1}{2}$ in the last equation (in the result).

Comment: @D.Rotnemer I've double-checked. You are referring to a non-existent step and my final answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write for the indefinite integral
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx$$ and $$3\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the integral:

$$\mathscr{I}_\text{n}:=\int_{2\text{n}}^{3\text{n}}\frac{3+x}{1+x^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_{2\text{n}}^{3\text{n}}\frac{3}{1+x^2}\space\text{d}x+\int_{2\text{n}}^{3\text{n}}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

1. Substitute $\text{u}=1+x^2$:
   $$\int_{2\text{n}}^{3\text{n}}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1+\left(2\text{n}\right)^2}^{1+\left(3\text{n}\right)^2}\frac{1}{\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\ln\left|1+\left(3\text{n}\right)^2\right|-\ln\left|1+\left(2\text{n}\right)^2\right|\tag2$$
2. $$\int_{2\text{n}}^{3\text{n}}\frac{3}{1+x^2}\space\text{d}x=3\int_{2\text{n}}^{3\text{n}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\space\text{d}x=3\cdot\left(\arctan\left(3\text{n}\right)-\arctan\left(2\text{n}\right)\right)\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}_\text{n}=\ln\left|1+\left(3\text{n}\right)^2\right|-\ln\left|1+\left(2\text{n}\right)^2\right|+3\cdot\left(\arctan\left(3\text{n}\right)-\arctan\left(2\text{n}\right)\right)\tag4$$

Now, we know that $\text{n}>0$:

$$\mathscr{I}_\text{n}=\ln\left(\frac{1+\left(3\text{n}\right)^2}{1+\left(2\text{n}\right)^2}\right)+3\cdot\left(\arctan\left(3\text{n}\right)-\arctan\left(2\text{n}\right)\right)\tag5$$

So, for the limit:

$$\text{L}:=\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\space\mathscr{I}_\text{n}=\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\left\{\ln\left(\frac{1+\left(3\text{n}\right)^2}{1+\left(2\text{n}\right)^2}\right)+3\cdot\left(\arctan\left(3\text{n}\right)-\arctan\left(2\text{n}\right)\right)\right\}=$$
$$\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{1+\left(3\text{n}\right)^2}{1+\left(2\text{n}\right)^2}\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\frac{18\text{n}}{8\text{n}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\tag6$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{9}{4})$

Comment: $\ln\left(\,{3/2}\,\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Letting $u=\frac{x}{n}$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int _{2n}^{3n}\frac{x+3}{x^2+1}\,dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int _{2}^{3}\frac{nu+3}{n^2u^2+1}\,ndu\\
&=&\int_2^3\frac1udu\\
&=&\ln\frac32.
\end{eqnarray}